# Angular - Assets returning 404 in library production build

Tags: angular, assets, production

I'm using ng serve to develop a Component Library in Angular.

Whenever I am running the development server, I am able to serve up assets because I have bundled them in on my project `angular.json` file. The project structure is like so:

```
angular-project
- projects
  - component-library
    - src
      - assets <- contains SVGs consumed by library
      - lib <- source code
- src
  - app
    app.component.ts
    app.component.html
    app.component.scss
    app.module.ts
angular.json <-- bundles projects/component-library/src/assets when running ng serve
```

I think this is where I've messed myself up. Inside my `angular.json` file, I have this:

```json
 "angular-project-name": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/angular-project",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/manifest.webmanifest",
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "./projects/component-library/src/assets",
                                "output": "/src/assets/"
                            } <-- HERE is where I bundle everything
                        ], 
                        ...
```

And then I can call for assets in code like so:

```js
export class SomeComponent {

    public get logoUrl(): string {
        switch (this.messageBarType) {
            case 'warning':
                return './src/assets/img/message-bar/string-icon-info-warn.svg';
            case 'severe-warning':
                return './src/assets/img/message-bar/string-icon-info-severe-warn.svg';
            case 'error':
                return './src/assets/img/message-bar/string-icon-info-error.svg';
            case 'blocked':
                return './src/assets/img/message-bar/string-icon-info-blocked.svg';
            case 'success':
                return './src/assets/img/message-bar/string-icon-info-success.svg';
            case 'info':
                return './src/assets/img/message-bar/string-icon-info-warn.svg';
        }

    }

}
```

And that works fine on the development server. But when I create a production build and push it to NPM, any call for assets returns 404. The assets folder definitely gets included with a production build as I can see it in the `dist` folder, and as far as I can tell, my `ng-package.json` file is correct:

```json
{
    "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
    "dest": "../../dist/component-library",
    "lib": {
        "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
    },
    "assets": [
        "./src/lib/**/*.scss",
        "./src/assets/**"
    ]
}
```

I've tried moving the assets folder about, I've tried changing the paths in code to point at the right place but I have had absolutely no luck in regards to a production build. Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up essentially creating my own custom icons module.

Because the assets are SVGs, and that will most likely always be the case, I created this type here:

```js
export interface INgxFluentDesignIcon {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly paths: Array<string>;
    readonly fill: string;
    readonly width: number;
    readonly height: number;
}
```

and then created a component which takes an INgxFluentDesignIcon like so:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { INgxFluentDesignIcon } from '../shared/types/ngx-fluent-design-icon.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-fluent-design-icon',
    templateUrl: './icon.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./icon.component.html']
})
export class NgxFluentDesignIconComponent {
    @Input() public icon: INgxFluentDesignIcon;
}
```

```html
<svg *ngIf="icon" [attr.width]="icon.width" [attr.height]="icon.height" [attr.viewBox]="'0 0' + ' ' + icon.width + ' ' + icon.height" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path *ngFor="let path of icon.paths" [attr.d]="path" [attr.fill]="icon.fill"></path>
</svg>
```

And the correct icon is now displayed on my components.

```js
 public get logoUrl(): INgxFluentDesignIcon {
        switch (this.messageBarType) {
            case 'warning':
                return NgxFluentDesignIconInfoWarn;
            case 'severe-warning':
                return NgxFluentDesignIconInfoSevereWarn;
            case 'error':
                return NgxFluentDesignIconInfoError;
            case 'blocked':
                return NgxFluentDesignIconInfoBlocked;
            case 'success':
                return NgxFluentDesignIconInfoSuccess;
            case 'info':
                return NgxFluentDesignIconInfoWarn;
        }
    }
```

This suits my needs perfectly. I still have no idea how to include assets with a production build of an Angular library though, so I will leave this open for a few more days.